# EAS Build:configure... git command not found

Tags: git, react-native, build, expo

EAS is giving me sass with building my react native app. If I run eas build [andoid,ios, or all] I get the following message:

```
Your Android project is not configured to build with EAS. Set it up now? » (Y/n)
```

I hit 'y' and then get this message.

```
Error: git command not found, install it before proceeding.
```

What git command? How do I install it? I can't find any other reference to anyone else having this problem. Any Ideas? Let me know if I can post any other information to help.

My eas-cli version is as follows: eas-cli/0.20.0 win32-x64 node-v12.19.0

This was a managed workflow that I then ejected to a bare workflow, but I was having this issue even before the eject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check first if git is in your `%PATH%` (Windows) or `$PATH` (Linux/Mac)

Simply type `git version`, before `eas build`: if the command fails, that would explain the error message.
If you don't have Git installed, install it first.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote eas build:configue inside the command prompt instead of git base I got the same error.

To fix: In VSCode open the terminal.
Click on the drop-down arrow next to the plus sign in the top righthand corner.
Select git bash.
Type git -v to check git version.
If git not installed download git at https://git-scm.com/downloads
Else type in eas build:configue and it should work.